# how to search for a arraylist element in a list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

suppose there is an array list

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

Console.WriteLine("Adding some numbers:");
al.Add(45);
al.Add(78);
al.Add(33);
al.Add(56);
```

and there is a list:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\\demo.xml");
     XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*");
    List<XmlNode> match = new List<XmlNode>();
foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodeList)
            {
    match.Add(node1.Attributes["match"]);
  }
```

how to search for a arraylist al element *"33"* in a list match

Comment: Have you tried anything? E.g. using `Linq`? Furthermore: what do you need? The index of the entry containing that number? The `XmlNode`? And last buit not least: consider using generic versions of collections such as `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: i tried "int ch = matchNode.indexOf(al);" But it gives an error as both are of different type

Comment: I just want to check whether arraylist substring exist in match or not

Comment: How does this even compile? You cannot add `10` to a list of `XmlNode` but instances of `XmlNode`.

Comment: sorry.. i made few changes to the code now

Comment: If it are just numbers, why don't you use `node1.Attributes["match"].Value` and add that to an int list? Of course make the arraylist also an int list since you are working with numbers?

Comment: int list won't allow "Attributes"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for items in an ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509501/searching-for-items-in-an-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if two lists have same value types , try this linkq.

```
var searchNum = al[2].ToString(); //add item for search 

 var results =  from value in match
 where value.ToString() == searchNum
 select value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a List this is how you can check values:

```
al.ToArray().Any(x => match.Exists(node => Convert.ToInt32(node.Value) == (int)x));
```

If you can use a List use this:

```
al.ToArray().Any(x => match.Exists(node => node.Value == (int)x));
```

Comment: the output of this will be a bool?

Comment: Yes. Any return a bool value